# Replace a char at Nth position

Tags: java

The main idea of this code to replace a char at a specific position.When I try to compile this code it gives me nothing, If I cane text2(For example: text2 = "lll" it shows me "lll". If it is possible give me a hint the way to solve my problem.  :)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String text3 = "Yeaaaaah";
    replaceNth(text3, 1, 'a', 'o');
}

public static String replaceNth(String text, int n, char oldValue, char newValue)
{
    String text2 = "";
    char[] array1 = text.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (array1[i] == oldValue) {
            if (i == n) {
                array1[i] = newValue;
                text2 = text.substring(0) + array1[i] + text.substring(i + 1);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(text2);
    }

    return text2;
}
```

Comment: Could you please put a modicum of effort into formatting your code so that it's readable? Thanks.

Comment: And your code is ***not*** a runnable JavaScript snippet.

Comment: What is the expected result and what do you get by executing that program (using "Yeaaaaah" as input)?

Comment: Let the compiler help you.  It is not useful to initialize `text2` in its declaration in method `replaceNth()`, because you never actually want to use the initial value you set in any way.  If you omit the initializer, then the compiler will report an error that will help explain your problem.  Solve that problem *the right way*.

Comment: @NPE Yes, I have tried. I will try to do it again. Thanks.

Comment: @Luke The expected result is "Yeoaaaah".

Comment: @JohnBollinger okay< I will try to cope with it. Thank you:)

Comment: and if the nth character isn't equal, it shouldn't do anything (i.e. if I pass 'e' as oldValue, it shouldn't change the string), right?

Comment: @Luke It should do it, we will have  "Yoaaaah" (If  oldValue is 'e' and newValue is 'o') If you have a little time and this problem is interesting for you, look at this https://www.codewars.com/kata/replace-every-nth/train/java. I think that I gave a bad explanation of my problem :)

Comment: Alright, I have misunderstood the question, will edit

Comment: @Sabina I have updated my answer, but I think you have misunderstood the question, or at least didn't provide accurate explanation in the question text. Clarify that and add link to the original answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyze the program step by step. Start from the for loop. First it checks whether array1[i] is equal to the old value. For the i==0, that is obviously false ('Y' != 'a'). Because it isn't true, it proceeds executing the else block which says: break; That means exit out of the loop and continue executing with the next statement (which would be System.out.println). Boom, nothing happens with the string, and since it was initialized to "" you get empty String back. Think about what would happen if array1[0] == oldChar, but n != 0 (hint: look at the inner if). Solution: remove elses.

The problem says you should replace every n-th occurrence of oldChar, so you should count how many character matches you have matched so far while iterating. Something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
    if(textChars[i]==oldChar) matches++;
    if(matches % n == 0) textChars[i] = newChar; //will match n, 2n, 3n,...
}
return String.valueOf(textChars);
```

Comment: and, by the way, you can also accept _and_ upvote an answer if you deem appropriate. Just saying

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very helpful, indeed .Unfortunately, I cannot vote, anyway I accepted it.

Comment: Right, I forgot about the rep restriction. Never mind, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I made this yesterday:

```
/*
Changes a character in a string with a character that you enter and returns the new string.
int i - character position
char c - new character
String msg - string that you are editing
*/

public class StringRemastered {
    public String setCharAt(int i, char c, String msg){
        char[] msgArray = msg.toCharArray();
        msgArray[i] = (char) c;
        msg = String.valueOf(msgArray);
        return msg;
    }
}
```

If the input is:

```
2, 'o', "Yeaaaaah"
```

The return value will be:

```
Yeoaaaah
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view it is unnecessary to use 'oldValue' as a parameter of your function. Please look at one of the possibility of function which replace single specified character inside given a String:

1. Create a list of all characters from given String ('word'),
2. Setting a new value for given 'position',
3. Create a StringBuilder and join all characters (with changed single char) into String 'result'.

   ```
   public static String replaceCharAtSpecificPosition(String word, int   position, char newValue){

      List<Character> chars = word.chars()
              .mapToObj(s -> (char)s)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());

      chars.set(position, newValue);

      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

      for(char eachChar: chars){
          result.append(eachChar);
      }

      return result.toString();
   }
   ```

Example of using this solution inside main:

```
    String word = "Yeeaaahh";

    String changedWord = replaceCharAtSpecificPosition(word, 2, 'Z');

    System.out.println(changedWord);
    //result: YeZaaahh
```