# How to replace special charactes on specific position

Tags: java, android, android-studio

what I want to do is to replace it with 9 if 3 is written in the 3rd character in a data. But I only want to do this for the 3rd character. How can I do it? This code I wrote replaces all 3's in the string with 9.

Regards...

```
    String adana = "123456789133";
    if (adana.length() > 2 && adana.charAt(2) == '3'){
            final String newText = adana.replace("3", "9");
            Log.d("TAG", "onCreate: " + newText);
    }
```

Comment: This answer shows how to convert the string to a char array and change the nth character and convert it back to a string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41859855/2711811.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try concatenating substrings:

```
 String adana = "123456789133";
 if (adana.length() > 2 && adana.charAt(2) == '3') {
     final String newText = adana.substring(0,2) + "9" + adana.substring(3);
     Log.d("TAG", "onCreate: " + newText);
 }
```

Comment: It also replaces when the third character does not appear `3`.

Comment: @mokyade thank you, clarified it must be replacing their single line of code

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
final String newText = adana.replaceAll("3(?<=^\\d{3})", "9");
```

The regex I used here uses positive look behind to search for occurrence of 3 in the 3rd position of the string. You can use `replaceAll()` or `replaceFirst()` since it accepts regex. Both case works.

Answer (score -1):

Your code checks relatively correctly, however you are failing to actually do the replacement. When using the `replace()` method of a string what java will do is replace all occurrences passed as the first parameter with the value passed in the second parameter. So naturally what you are talking about will happen. One way to solve this in this specific case is to do:

```java
String adana = "123456789133";
StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < adana.length(); i++) {
    if (i == 2 && adana.charAt(2) == '3') {
        newText.append('9');
    } else {
        newText.append(adana.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

This strategy will work for any string of any length.

Or if you don't want to use string builders (which is not recommended in this case), you can do:

```java
String newText = "";
for (int i = 0; i < adana.length(); i++) {
    if (i == 2 && adana.charAt(2) == '3') {
        newText += "9";
    } else {
        newText += adana.charAt(i);
    }
}
```